# Spring - NoSuchBeanDefinitionException when autowiring Repository into Service

Tags: java, spring, service, dependency-injection, repository

I am trying to Autowire a repository into a Service that's called from a Controller, but I keep getting the following error message:

```
Error creating bean with name 'mktPlace2PedidoService' defined in VFS resource [\"/home/davidgarcia/wildfly-11.0.0.Final/standalone/deployments/issuer.war/WEB-INF/classes/br/com/sinergico/service/mktplace2/MktPlace2PedidoService.class\"]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor argument with index 0 of type [br.com.sinergico.repository.mktplace2.MktPlace2PedidoRepository]: No qualifying bean of type [br.com.sinergico.repository.mktplace2.MktPlace2PedidoRepository] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {}; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [br.com.sinergico.repository.mktplace2.MktPlace2PedidoRepository] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {}
```

The odd thing is that I have many other repositories being used in the exact same way, but not giving this problem...

Here is my call to the repository in the **Service** constructor

```
package br.com.sinergico.service.mktplace2;

@Service
public class MktPlace2PedidoService extends GenericService<MktPlace2Pedido, Long> {

    private MktPlace2PedidoRepository repository;

    @Autowired
    public MktPlace2PedidoService(MktPlace2PedidoRepository repository) {
        super(repository);
        this.repository = repository;
    }

    //other methods
}
```

Here is the **Repository**

```
package br.com.sinergico.repository.mktplace2;

public interface MktPlace2PedidoRepository extends JpaRepository<MktPlace2Pedido, Long> {
    //some methods   
}
```

And here is the **Entity** declaration

```
package br.com.entity.mktplace2;

@Entity
@Table(name="pedido", schema = "marketplace")
@SequenceGenerator(name="hibernate_sequence",    sequenceName="marketplace.hibernate_sequence",initialValue=1, allocationSize=1)
public class MktPlace2Pedido implements Serializable{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 45381343130121532L;

    @Id
    @Column(name="id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "hibernate_sequence")
    private Long id;

    //other columns

}
```

I have tried including the @Repository annotation to the repository, but it didn't do anything.

Can anyone help? I've spent hours on this and can't figure it out...

---

**EDIT - SOLUTION**

Thanks to davidxxx the problem was solved. I was missing the package inside the @EnableJpaRepositories, now it looks something like this:

```
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = { ... ,"br.com.sinergico.repository.mktplace2", ... })
```

Comment: Your repository is in the same jar as your service? What's your configuration class look like?

Comment: Make sure your `repository` is in same base package

Comment: The repository is in the same jar as my service. It is also in the same base package. I'll add the packages to the question text.
We are not working with a configuration xml class here, so I'm not really sure about how it looks. I'll look into that

Comment: Just a guesswork : you declared/enabled`@EnableJpaRepositories` with a `basePackages` not a parent package of the `br.com.sinergico.repository.mktplace2` package.

Comment: Woah! Great guess, @davidxxx !! That was it. Thanks a lot!! Post your comment as an answer and I'll  mark it as the one that solved the problem. I can't do that on a comment

Comment: @David Silva  Glad that it could helped you :) To make helpful the question and the answer to other users, I propose you to first update the question to expose the part with the `@EnableJpaRepositories` that caused the issue.

Comment: @davidxxx Done!

Comment: @David Silva Thanks. Did an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This annotation  :

```
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = ...)
```

will enable JPA repositories according to the value given to the `basePackages` attribute.
Generally you have two ways of using it :

- either you specify a single `String` value that corresponds to the package or the parent package where your `JpaRepository`s are declared.
- or you specify multiple `String` values that correspond to each package of each of your `JpaRepository`s.

Actually, you seem using the second strategy as it works for some Repositories but not for this one.   So you have to explicitly add the package of this repository :

```
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = { ... ,"br.com.sinergico.repository.mktplace2", ... })
```

Note that the first way (using a single value as `basePackages` ) should be favored as much as possible as it allows to  add/remove of new Repository without the need to update the  `basePackages` annotation.

Answer (score 1):

You didn't create any bean of your MktPlace2PedidoRepository. Annotate your interface with @Repository.
Another think, use @EnableJpaRepositories("br.com.sinergico.repository") to give Spring information where to find Repository classes to create beans

Comment: The [@Repository] annotation didn't make a difference in this case. But the [@EnableJpaRepositories] did! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Add @Repository Annotation for the Repository interface MktPlace2PedidoRepository

Also,

Remove Constructor from MktPlace2PedidoService and Add @Autowired for the Repository field

Comment: The problem was that I hadn't added the package to the @EnableJpaRepositories annotation